# Variance estimation of the dependent variable in a Gaussian GAM (MGCV package)?

Tags: r, variance, gam

Consider the code below:

```
library(mgcv)

set.seed(123)
X = runif(300, 0, 1)
set.seed(123)
Y = X^3 + 2*X^2 + 1 + rnorm(300)

model = gam(Y~s(X), family= gaussian)
```

So `model` is a Gaussian generalized additive model (GAM). How can I find the estimated variance of the dependent variable (`Y`) in `model`?

**UPDATE**: In generalized additive models, when the family is Gaussian, the scale parameter is equal to the variance of `Y`. So I think I can use `summary(model)$scale` which gives the scale parameter estimation in fact, but can also be taken equal to the variance estimation of `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this directly from the model object via the `sig2` component of the fitted model:

```
> summary(model)$scale
[1] 0.9006256
> model$sig2
[1] 0.9006256
```

The `scale.estimated` component also tells you if this was estimated by the model or supplied:

```
> model$scale.estimated
[1] TRUE
```